# Spotfire expression - get the minimum of the next indicator per id

Tags: spotfire

for every id, I am trying to get the minimum date of the next indicator next to the previous indicator. it is similar to lead in sql. the wished result is in the column target.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OUMOUSS_ELMEHDI - Below OVER function should give you the desired result.

```
Min([Timestamp]) OVER (Intersect(Next([Indicator]),[ID]))
```

**Here is the final result table:**

[image]

Comment: beautiful solution, thanks a lot. intersect followed by a next function that is cool !